# How to iterate the folder insider folder using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

1.All parquet is available in the blob storage. Below is the folder structure.

```
FileInfo(path='wasbs://abcd@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/14-57-55/', name='14-57-55/', size=0)
FileInfo(path='wasbs://abcd@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/15-10-33/', name='15-10-33/', size=0)
FileInfo(path='wasbs://abcd@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/17-07-47/', name='17-07-47/', size=0)
```

2.If we you see here there are multiple subdirectories `("dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/14-57-55/")` inside the container and inside the 2020-12-16 folder again having multiple sub folders. So As per the requirement we need to pick the latest timestamp from `date(2020-12-16/17-07-47/)` 
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Databricks, you can use [Databricks Utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#ls-command-dbutilsfsls) Python package `dbutils.fs` to loop through the list of directory and get the latest timestamp as your requirement.

```py
files = [
    'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/14-57-55/',
    'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/15-10-33/',
    'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/17-07-47/'
]

sorted(files)[-1]
# wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/17-07-47/
```

Comment: Yes i have used this command the below command  for folder in FileInfo:
      for Subfolder in dbutils.fs.ls(folder.path):
               SubfolderPath.append(Subfolder.path)

Comment: So you can loop through it and grab the exact file/folder that you want, right?

Comment: The ouput is returning ['wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/14-57-55/',
 'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/15-10-33/',
 'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/17-07-47/]

Comment: yes i want to pick the latest timetsmap path

Comment: sure, check my updated answer :)

Comment: In this case we have only one date (2020-10-16) but what if we have multiple date folders and subfolders inside that

Comment: ['wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/14-57-55/',
 'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/15-10-33/',
 'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-16/17-07-47/,
'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-17/14-57-55/',
 'wasbs://Containername@Storagename.blob.core.windows.net/dir1/dir2/2020-12-17/15-10-33/']